# "Hangman" game. Instead of letters, the inscription is displayed "tresc_diva"

Tags: javascript

I have function:

function start() {

```
var tresc_diva = "";

for (i=0; i<34; i++) {

    tresc_diva = tresc_diva + '<div class="litera">A</div>';


}

document.getElementById("alfabet").innerHTML = "tresc_diva"; 

wypisz_haslo();
```

}

The whole code: https://codepen.io/Nieuport/pen/bWRMdR

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Can you give more details? What's not working?

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
document.getElementById("alfabet").innerHTML = "tresc_diva";
```

Sets the innerHTML to the string "tresc_diva". You probably simply want to remove the quotes:

```
document.getElementById("alfabet").innerHTML = tresc_diva;
```

Comment: I was just about to post the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the string "tresc_diva" to the innerHTML property, You want to assign the tresc_diva variable.